# Consequence of using 3d Printed Caddy in HP Gen9 server?

Tags: hp-proliant

I understand that HP Gen9 server caddies have a chip and some lights on them.

What is the consequence of using drives in a 3d printed caddy (ie without the lights or management chip present in the official caddies)?

I expect to makes little difference, but I'm referring to the 2.5" caddies

Comment: Why did someone make a 3d model of them if they don't work?

Comment: @moab But conversely Why would HP go to the effort of adding a chip to their caddies? Some stuff Ive read online implies consequences like loss of hot-plug capability, forcing fans on 24/7 and RAID degraded  messages. All of these things appear hand-wavey and uncorroborated/unofficial, hence my question.  (There are actually a few 3d models of them but none I could find with comments on if they work)

Comment: I doubt anyone here has tried one, you may have to be the guinea pig. Google returns very little on the caddy chips.